Github Actions: Creating Google Pub/Sub Topic
Code that works
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  pre-commit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: python:3.11
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.11
      - name: Install pre-commit
        run: pip install pre-commit
      - name: Run pre-commit
        run: pre-commit run --all-files

  create-pubsub-topic_new:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name: Setup GCP Service Account
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@main
        with:
          project_id: "cicdtest-421422"
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}

When I add following
      - name: Check and Create Pub/Sub topic
        run: |
          if ! gcloud pubsub topics describe weather-topic > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            gcloud pubsub topics create weather-topic
            echo "Topic 'weather-topic' created."
          else
            echo "Topic 'weather-topic' already exists."
        shell: bash
        env:
          CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
          CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 2.1.0

I receive such error
Run if ! gcloud pubsub topics describe weather-topic > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  if ! gcloud pubsub topics describe weather-topic > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    gcloud pubsub topics create weather-topic
    echo "Topic 'weather-topic' created."
  else
    echo "Topic 'weather-topic' already exists."
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail ***0***
  env:
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 2.1.0
/home/runner/work/_temp/4734248d-58bd-4d9f-bea6-464635c0ad97.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

I tried googling / using chat-gtp and neither have worked.
I did the same on gitlab with other script and it works.
My Aim is to create weather-topic Google Pub/Sub Topic if does not exist and pass if exists arleady

You must terminate Bash if with fi. See e.g. Using If Else in Bash Scripts

For additional security and reduced complexity consider using Workload Identity Federation to authenticate your GitHub (and GitLab) actions. See Enabling keyless auth with GitHub actions and Configure WIF with deployment pipelines

Adding fi changed nothing, will investigate further

I was able to repro your issue by omitting the terminating fi statement and to resolve your issue by adding the terminating fi statement.

I suggest you to use Terraform for managing infrastructure on the cloud

Managed to solve this, Issue was there was no authentication

The issue was code was lacking authentication
Final code below
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  pre-commit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: python:3.11
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Change directory to repository root
      run: cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.11
          
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Initialize Git
      run: git init  # Optional step if needed

    - name: Cache pre-commit hooks
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pre-commit
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-precommit-${{ hashFiles('.pre-commit-config.yaml') }}

    - name: Install pre-commit
      run: pip install pre-commit

    - name: Run pre-commit with debug
      run: pre-commit run --all-files

  create-pubsub-topic_new:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name: Setup GCP Service Account
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@main
        with:
          project_id: "cicdtest-421422"
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}

      - name: Setup GCP Service Account
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
           credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}          

      - name: Check and Create Pub/Sub topic
        run: |
          if ! gcloud pubsub topics describe weather-topic > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            gcloud pubsub topics create weather-topic
            echo "Topic 'weather-topic' created."
          else
            echo "Topic 'weather-topic' already exists."
          fi
        shell: bash
        env:
          CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
          CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 2.1.0

